# Not getting data in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i am not able to get data through react-redux all my code is well placed i am not getting output using any of the api i am using json placeholder api for testing please check  below is my code

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore (
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);


export default store;
```

**rootReducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import productReducer from './productReducer';

const rootReducers = combineReducers({
    product: productReducer,
});

export default rootReducers;
```

**productReducer**

```
const initialState = {
    categories: [],
};

export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_CATEGORY':
            return {
                ...state,
                categories: action.payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**productAction**

```
export const getCategory = () => (dispatch) => {

        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'GET_CATEGORY',
                payload: res.data
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.message, err.data.status));
            dispatch(clearErrorMessages());
        });
};
```

**categories.js**

```
import { getCategory} from '../../actions/productActions';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Categories = memo(() => {
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productData = useSelector((state) => state.product);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getCategory(dispatch);
    }, [dispatch])

    console.log(productData.categories);
});
```

i am getting output as a blank array any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are dispatching the action incorrectly.

Should be like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCategory());
}, [dispatch,getCategory])
```

Comment: thank u so much its fix my error :)